# SAML IdP Implementation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, saml

I am new to SAML IdP Single Sign-on Implementation and looking for a cloud service or a framework that helps to build an IdP (.Net MVC Framework) for already logged in users but just to authenticate with a service provider with a unqiue identifier. After a user has logged  in, I want to build an IdP service that posts an assertion to the Service provider with a unique key in the assertion subject and display the SP's metadata info in the website.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-idp-to-test-now-477761595b60).

There's a list of public SAML IDP that should be enough to get you going.